# Constructor Definition C++

Tags: c++, constructor

I've the following class in C++:

```
class IntStack
{
    private:
        int *stackArray;
        int stackSize;
        int top;

    public:
        IntStack(int);          // Constructor
        // rest of the 
        // member function
};
```

I've defined the constructor outside the class as:

```
IntStack::IntStack(int size)
{
    stackArray = new int[size];
    stackSize = size;
    top = -1;
}
```

Error here is: `initializing argument 1 of 'IntStack::IntStack(int)`

I've created instance of the same class as:

```
cout << endl << "Enter size of Stack: ";
cin  >> stackCapacity;
IntStack stack = new IntStack(stackCapacity);
```

Error here is: `invalid conversion from 'IntStack*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]`

How to sort out these errors?

Comment: Try `IntStack stack{stackCapacity};`

Comment: `new` dynamically allocates an `IntStack` on the heap and then returns its address (an `IntStack*`). `stack` however is not an `IntStack*` but an `IntStack` you are creating on the stack.

Comment: `IntStack stack = new IntStack(stackCapacity);` -> `IntStack *stack = new IntStack(stackCapacity);`

Comment: @Eljay no success

Comment: @EdHeal yes it done the trick

Comment: @EdHeal -- even better: `IntStack stack(stackCapacity);`. <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker - depends.

Comment: Why don't you just use a `std::vector<int>` or `std::stack<int>` instead of this class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`new IntStack(stackCapacity);` is allocating space for an `IntStack` on the heap and returning a pointer to the newly allocated memory. You're trying to then put this pointer into your `IntStack` variable.

Either change `stack` to be a pointer:

```
IntStack *stack = new IntStack(stackCapacity);
```

Or don't allocate memory on the heap:

```
IntStack stack(stackCapacity);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can defined the `constructor` outside the class as you did. But problem is in the below statement where you are trying to allocate memory for `stack` from `heap`.

```
IntStack stack = new IntStack(stackCapacity); /* stack should be of pointer type */
```

Should be

```
IntStack *stack = new IntStack (stackCapacity);
```

Answer (score -5):

Add an `explicit` keyword to your constructor. I think it tries to convert your argument to instance class object to do a copy construction.